# Reading 2 RSS feeds at ones and mix the results

Tags: php, rss, simplexml, feed

For a schoolproject I need a way to read multiple RSS feeds from different newssites and show them on my website. Now I got the part that I load in the RSS feeds with SimpleXML, but than I got first a list from one feed and than a list for the other feed. But i just want the results to be mixed on publication date.

I already tried [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort) but than it sort per feed and not the total list.

Comment: For what its worth, SimplePie (http://simplepie.org/) does this for you, and is much more forgiving about the kinds of feeds it can deal with.

Comment: First combine, then sort. Job done. Better look for one problem at once, you will find good resources on this website already then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download multiple xml at once take  look at curl_multi_exec ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php )